# My Apache2 server got pwned, need some help uncovering impact

Tags: apache2

So I'm pretty sure that my home Apache2 server got hacked. This is in a VM running on my server. I was using this server as a https proxy/reverse-proxy for my other applications I have running at home.

What happened was that I created a too small disk and that got full. Then, it got full and my unattended upgrades weren't running anymore. I was stuck at apache 2.4.38. That's completely my fault.

What I noticed was that on one of my subdomains I got a page displaying a default InteractSH server message. I never installed this interactSH server. So I got to work and just found out that the subdomain in question is somehow magically being routed to a malicious IP. (It's also marked as malicious over at maltiverse.com).

I want to know a few things:

- Where on earth does this routing take place?
- What has likely been compromised?
- How do I find out for how long I've been compromised?

On the first questions, I use a direct IP address to connect the apache2 server to my backed server.  "ip route list" shows nothing. My hosts file shows nothing either. This is what my config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.access.log combined

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=1552000; includeSubDomains"

<Location />
ProxyPass http://192.168.my.local.ip/
ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.my.local.ip/
</Location>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

SSLCertificateFile /etc/path...
SSLCertificatKeyFile /etc/path...

</VirtualHost>
```

On the second questions, I don't know what they could have done over the last while. In theory they could have snooped all my traffic couldn't they? Or could have stolen my SSL certificates.

Can anyone give me some leads or support on what to do?

Regards,
TTheCreator

Comment: "the subdomain in question is somehow magically being routed to a malicious IP": is your Apache server redirecting traffic with a HTTP Location header, or has the IP of the subdomain been changed? In case of the latter, the problem of your hack lies at your DNS management. On a side note, an not up-to-date Apache 2.4 is not *that* vulnerable that it immediately leads to remote code execution. Something else is probably going on.

Comment: Hi @Halfgaar, my DNS settings are intact. I'll update my original post with an example of what my apache config looks like. The website really appears to be coming from my subdomain, but is routed away somehow.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, this helps a lot. I can get a lot of general information out of that. However, in my specific case I'd like details on finding out how my data was routed. This way I can find out what data was routed. I need to know if my data was tapped and if so for how long.